# Switching camera view on multiple cameras form python

Tags: python, camera

I've created 3 cameras in my scene and I need to go from the first to the last always in camera view.

What's wrong is that if I start my code in camera perspective, the camera changes and so do the view correctly.

But if i launch my code in user perspective, the cameras will switch correctly but the view not until the end, where it will go in the last camera's perspective

```
for w in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    s = w.screen
    for a in s:
        if a.type = 'VIEW_3D':
            for r in a.regions:
                if r.type='WINDOW':
                    override = {'window':w, 'screen':s, 'area':a, 'region':r}    

by.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(override, type='CAMERA')
for c in [c for c in bpy.context.scene.objects if c.type == 'CAMERA']:
    bpy.context.scene.camera = c
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations = 1)
```

Seems like the viewnumpad() is not triggering correctly the view before the switching. How can fix it?

Comment: is the same code you are running ? there is an error in `REDRAW_WIN_SWAP`

Comment: pardon, I forgot the override for the view_numpad() context. Edited.

Comment: no i did the override part but as i said there is no `REDRAW_WIN_swap`

Comment: still my fault. It's DRAW_WIN_SWAP....don't know why I wrote that :)

Comment: did you take a look at [this DOC](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/info_gotcha.html?highlight=redraw_timer#can-i-redraw-during-the-script)

Comment: yes it's where I found the redraw method. I know that it's not a good practice use the redraw_timer()...are you telling me that this may be one of those case where the redraw fails? :\

Comment: I guess we have to wait for one of the blender  experts to drop by, but i'll keep digging :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears clearly when moving from any view to camera_view but it is also present when moving from camera_view to another (you can see that the view change from camera than hold still and then change at last) and it is caused by the `ED_view3d_smooth_view_ex()` ( [source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_view.c;e8b6d86f9514b86daefe6ee0182c57d794b603f9$164) ) function  and as you can see in the source code it is skipped if you are in render view , so for checking you can switch to render view and the code will run as expected

here some code to make the transition clear (watch the view and console ) :

```
def main(context):
    print('******************************************************')
    bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(type='CAMERA')
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations = 1)
    print('sleep')
    time.sleep(8)
    print('wake')
```

---

( it may have something to do with timers )

Comment: you're right, in render view it works correctly. Otherwise I can't do it in this way because if my scene starts to be heavy, any transition will require too much time; in this case doing it starting from the a camera view will be lighter. By the way thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @UncleSax you're welcome, and if it is critical to your application ask the developers for any work around